# How to get only active Ad Sets of a Facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm struggling to get a list of ad sets which are currently active.

I'm using the following to get a list of ad sets:

...account ID/adcampaigns?fields=campaign_status

This returns all ACTIVE and PAUSED ad sets.

How can I filter only the active ones? The answer is probably very easy, but I just don't figure it out. (I'm fairly new to APIs)

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3#read-adaccount):

```
...account ID/adcampaigns?fields=campaign_status&campaign_status=['ACTIVE']
```

will return only the ACTIVE Ad Sets in the Account

It returns ACTIVE and PAUSED by default

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried a lot of combinations but not this one it seems.